# Treatment of PHP loops which are open and correct formatting

Tags: php, html

Very new to PHP and know a little HTML.

All these question spawned from the author's coding style.  Which looks interesting, but then the way the code works doesn't seem to make sense.

1. I couldn't understand why the author is suggesting a separate `<?php ?>` tag for each line in html.  Is this best style/coding practice?
2. Because of the author's style, I couldn't understand why the line `<li><?php echo $product['name']; ?></li>` is not put into a php tag of its own.  For me "li" tag should sit inside the php tag, and then echoed out... but nope, what the author did works correctly to display the content.
3. Because of 2, I went to experiment with the code below.  I've added in text where I think is just plain text where I expected to output once, and not go through a PHP loop.  But nope... looping is happening even though the text is not in the PHP code itself.

Fully confused.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
<?php
    $products = [
        ['name' => 'shiny star', 'price' => 20],
        ['name' => 'green shell', 'price' => 10],
        ['name' => 'red shell', 'price' => 15],
        ['name' => 'gold coin', 'price' => 5],
        ['name' => 'lightning bolt', 'price' => 40],
        ['name' => 'banana skin', 'price' => 2],
    ];
?>

<... snip to show only body..>
    <body>
        <div class="">
            <ul>
                Not php section
                <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
                    Should be plain text with no repeat.  Inside First. Outside second.
                    <?php if ($product['price'] > 15) { ?>
                        <li><?php echo $product['name']; ?></li>
                        Should be plain text.  Inside second.
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Output:

Not php section Should be plain text with no repeat. Inside First. Outside second.
shiny star
Should be plain text. Inside second. Should be plain text with no repeat. Inside First. Outside second. Should be plain text with no repeat. Inside First. Outside second. Should be plain text with no repeat. Inside First. Outside second. Should be plain text with no repeat. Inside First. Outside second.
lightning bolt
Should be plain text. Inside second. Should be plain text with no repeat. Inside First. Outside second.

Comment: I suggest using this syntax instead `<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>` and close with `<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Short answer to your question, the PHP interpreter first will read the entire file looking for PHP tags and then will interpret according to the tokens (brackets and sentences) found, that's why it works but I recommend to use the template syntax as I commented before :)

Comment: 1) It is a style, some ppl use it, some don't. AFAIK it was popular with Wordpress years ago, non-MVC applications where code is mixed into views. 2) Again, it is just style/preference, but if it isn't PHP (`<li>` is just text), why would you get PHP to echo it? 3) If you are asking why `with no repeat` is repeated, think about it.  You have an array (a set, if you like) of products, and are iterating over them.  The outside loop will happen once for each item in the set.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule I go for is to only wrap PHP tags around the smallest thing possible.

So for the example, HTML tags don't NEED to be echoed, it's just the variables and loop that require it, so I would go for a similar style.

One way to think about it, is to think of text outside PHP tags like an implicit echo.

That might better explain why number 3 is tripping you up. 
"Should be plain text with no repeat..." is between the opening and close braces of the foreach loop, so WILL be repeated.

So it's equivalent to something like this which would obviously repeat:

```php
<?php
  foreach($products as $product) {
    echo "Should be plain text with no repeat.  Inside First. Outside second.";
    // ... the rest
  }
?>
```

As @OsDev mentioned in the comments, when using PHP as a templating language in this way, it's also common to use the [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), which makes it easier to read without correct indentation. (if/while/for/foreach/switch all have alternative syntax versions)

I'd also recommend looking into templating languages such as [Twig (Symfony framework)](https://twig.symfony.com/) and [Blade (Laravel framework)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade), which are the more modern way of interspersing PHP and markup in modern PHP

Comment: OK cool. Thanks for that.  Implicit echo makes sense.  I haven't learnt anything on alternative syntax yet, so that's just way too much for me to digest right now. I'll have a look the templating languages.